# Given a list of positive and negative numbers. What is an elegant solution to tell which is closest to zero?

Tags: javascript

Say you have a list of numbers:

```
var list = [4, -12, 18, 1, -3];
```

What is a more elegant solution to finding the value closest to zero without nesting a whole lot of if/else statements?

Comment: Elegant? Let's just start with a solution. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Run through the `Math.abs` function then use the usual method to find the lowest number.

Comment: What should happen if there's a tie?

Comment: Have you tried something? If this isn't actually a solution to a problem you're having maybe this would be better on code golf

Answer (score 4):

use reduce:

```
list.reduce((pre,cur) => Math.abs(pre) > Math.abs(cur) ? cur : pre)
```

Answer (score 0):

use sort :

```
list.sort((a,b) => Math.abs(a)-Math.abs(b))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do with a single traversal of the array.

```js
function findClosestToZero(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return;
  }

  var closeNumber = Math.abs(arr[0]);

  arr.forEach(function(number) {
    if (Math.abs(number) < closeNumber) {
      closeNumber = Math.abs(number)
    }
  });
  return closeNumber;
}


var arr = [-5, 98, -4, 7, 9, 213, 4, -2, 1];
console.log(findClosestToZero(arr));
```

Answer (score -2):

1. get the absolute value of all numbers

   ```
   Math.abs()
   ```
2. sort the number in ascending order

   ```
   Array.sort()
   ```

   The first number is the required answer.

Comment: This won't necessarily return the original values (eg. -1 is the closest, would return 1)